# adjustResize pushes EditText up but not the RecyclerView above it

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` to push the `EditText` and RecyclerView up when keyboard appears, but it only works on the EditText. `RecyclerView` stays in the same position (thus some elements are not visible). What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="co.bla.bla.ChatActivity"
    android:id="@+id/chat_root">

<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chat_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/message_input_wrapper"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_input_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/chat_input_hint"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/message_send_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chat_button_text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know how `adjustResize` exactly works, but I assume when using `android:layout_above` in this case, the `RecyclerView` and `LinearLayout` "stick" together and should be pushed up together?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @Vincent_Paing no, unfortunately!

Answer (score 3):

In your activity manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Then add an OnLayoutChangeListener to yout recyclerView:

```
recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,int oldRight, int oldBottom)
            {
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1);
            }
        });
```

This works for me :)

Answer (score -2):

set a soft keyboard listener:

```
private boolean mLastKeyBoardVisible = false;
private void addOnSoftKeyBoardVisibleListener(final OnSoftKeyBoardVisibleListener listener) {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
            int displayHight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            int hight = decorView.getHeight();
            boolean visible = (double) displayHight / hight < 0.8;

            if(visible != mLastKeyBoardVisible){
                listener.onSoftKeyBoardVisible(visible);
            }
            mLastKeyBoardVisible = visible;
        }
    });
}

private OnSoftKeyBoardVisibleListener onSoftKeyBoardVisibleListener = new OnSoftKeyBoardVisibleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSoftKeyBoardVisible(boolean visible) {
        scrollToBottom(visible);
    }
};

synchronized private void scrollToBottom(boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        if (mMessageList.size() != messageAdapter.getItemCount() && mMessageList.size() > 0) {
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            messageListView.scrollToPosition(mMessageList.size() - 1);
        } else if (mMessageList.size() > 0) {
            messageListView.scrollToPosition(mMessageList.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```